# Instantiating actors without explicitly knowing them by name

Tags: java, routes, akka, actor

I am looking forward to using AKKA (with Java) for a hierarchical system of distributed agents, relatively independent of one another. There would be a single coordinating actor, which is given a message. It must create a number of children actors, without knowing them explicitly, and route a message to them. The children actors extend an AppWorker class, by contract.

I thought about using reflection to simply pick up all classes that extend from AppWorker, and create an instance of each. Maybe AKKA has a better way to do this that I may not know about. My big concern is if by explicitly calling `actorOf`, I would later on be able to configure my app to scale to more than one machine. I want to keep AKKA's total freedom of load-balancing actor creation between machines.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

AKKA creates actors in a hierarchial manner. First, a Parent actor is created which in turn creates children to perform the set of sub taks required.
Create a class of the single co-ordinating actor and create an AKKA actor in the below manner : 
1. Create a actor system with the class name of the single co-ordinating actor.
2. Use the actorOf() method of the actor system and and create the parent actor.

Now create child actors by invoking the actorOf() method of the Parent actor and using the withRouter() method. You can give the number of child actors you want to create in the conf file. Also you can mention the supervision strategy you require while initiating the child actors.

For all AKKA based research on actors and how to initiate them please refer to http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/general/actor-systems.html and http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/general/actors.html.